# How can I override a multi word command with an alias in zsh?

Tags: zsh

I'm trying to override `docker ps` to be `docker ps --format="table {{.ID}} {{.Image}} {{.Status}}"`

I've read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11380263/206466) and the referenced documentation, but I can't get it to work.

I've tried a few things that "compile", here's the latest attempt.

```bsh
alias func='dockerps'

function dockerps() {
 'docker ps'='docker ps --format="table {{.ID}} {{.Image}} {{.Status}}"'$\
}
```

How can I fix my code such that typing `docker ps` will preserve my formatting?

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as a multi-word alias. The SO answer you refer to seems plain mistaken to me: it doesn't make any sense, and I can't find any trace of any feature that would yield anything close to the desired effect, even when digging through the zsh history to look for a possible experimental feature in 4.3 (the development version of zsh at the time) that would have been removed before the 5.0 release. What you wrote has a well-defined meaning: it defines an alias for `func` and a function called `dockerps`, so it only has an effect on command line where the first word is `func` or `dockerps`. If the function is ever invoked, it attempts to set a variable with an invalid name, which fails.

Zsh lets you can define an alias for a word that includes special characters, for example

```
darkstar% alias "'docker ps'"='echo docker ps in single quotes'
darkstar% alias 'docker\ ps'='echo docker backslash ps'                 
darkstar% 'docker ps'
docker ps in single quotes
darkstar% docker\ ps
docker backslash ps
darkstar% "docker ps"
zsh: command not found: docker ps
```

But this is not particularly useful. `'docker ps'` is one word but `docker ps` is two words.

You'll have to do it the normal way: define a function called `docker`, and have it analyze its argument. Here's a simple version that supports global options, but requires using `--option=value` rather than `--option value` for global options that take an argument.

```
docker () {
  setopt local_options extended_glob unset
  local -i i=$argv[(i)^-*]
  # $argv[i] is the first non-option argument (or empty if there is none).
  # See if we want to insert something after it.
  case $argv[i] in
    ps) argv[i+1,i]=(--format="table {{.ID}} {{.Image}} {{.Status}}");;
  esac
  command docker "$@"
}
```

Comment: It's called out in the README for 5.4.2.  It didn't do what people thought that it did in any event.

Comment: @JdeBP What are you referring to? I don't see anything that would have allowed multi-word aliases, or that would have made `'docker ps'=…` not be an error, or that would have made the code shown in the question have any effect on a command starting with `docker ps`.

Comment: The `README` for the Z shell, under the heading "Incompatibilities between 5.3.1 and 5.4.2", item #1.  And as I said, the code referenced by the question (and your answer) in the Stack Overflow answer didn't do what people thought that it did in any event.

Comment: @JdeBP That was about defining (or attempting to define) an alias and a function with the same name, which isn't what that SO answer does. It's also the wrong time frame for that SO answer.

Comment: On the contrary, it's _exactly_ what the answer does.  They're both named `func`, or rather apparently so.  The `README` explains what _really_ used to happen, before 5.4.2.

Comment: @JdeBP Oh, my bad, I hadn't realized that the SO answer didn't follow the same pattern as the U&L question. But even so, the SO answer didn't work before 5.4.2 either.

Comment: IMO `$argv[i]` would make it more legible than `${(P)i}` especially considering you're already using `argv[i+1,i]` in that code.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, like in `csh` where that `alias` misfeature comes from, you could do:

```
alias docker='docker '
alias     ps='ps --format="table {{.ID}} {{.Image}} {{.Status}}"'
```

Which would achieve what you want but that would mean that:

1. All words following `docker` would be subject to alias expansion (that `alias cmd='cmd '` trick is intended for commands like `command`, `env`, `sudo` that take commands as arguments so aliases are also expanded after them).
2. A `ps` word without `docker` before it would also be expanded, which means you couldn't run the standalone `ps` command anymore unless you change the wording of the invocation (like `"ps" -ef`).

Here, I'd just define a new *command* with a different name, so it doesn't clash with the original that does what you want:

```
my-docker-ps() docker ps --format="table {{.ID}} {{.Image}} {{.Status}}" "$@"
```

Here implemented as a function, though you may prefer to implement it as a script instead so it's also available outside of your shell.